# $Z=\{p(x,y):p(x,y)=0\}$. Is the complement connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider polynomials $p(x,y)$ in two (real) variables, $p \not= 0$ For each such $p$, let

$Z=Z(p)=\{(x,y):p(x,y)=0\}$.

If $Z$ contains more than one point, can the complement of $Z$ be connected?

I can't think of a way for this to happen, but I can't see how to prove it can't happen either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be connected. Consider the product of two or more polynomials with one root. For instance, $p(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can make $Z$ be any finite set of points by inserting $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$ as a factor. This will be zero iff $x=a$ and $y=b$. You can consider products of a finite number of these polynomials to obtain an arbitrary finite set of points.